# How to load large data into UITableView without blocking UI

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview where i need to show around 10,000 rows (data stored locally in sqlite)

But when we jump to that view, app is getting blocked (freezed) as its loading all those rows.

Is there anyway to load data without freezing UI?

PS. Our app is rejected, is it because of this reason?

Thanks

EDIT:
They rejected and given following info
"Hello.

We noticed your app lacks native iOS functionality.

Please check out the videos for app design information,: "Getting Started
video: The Ingredients of Great iPhone Apps" and "iPhone User Interface
Design," available on the iOS Developer
Centerhttp://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios,
and the iOS Human Interface
Guidelineshttp://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdfin
particular, the sections, "Great
iOS Apps Embrace the Platform and HI Design
Principles"http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.htmland
"Human
Interface Principles"http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Principles/Principles.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW1."

Comment: When an app is rejected, they usually **tell** you a reason.

Comment: why don't you use Load More Concept...? First only show 25 Data. and When user scrolls down at that time load another 25 more data........

Comment: @PhillipMills i have added reason above
but basically they don't give clear reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) demo for lazy loading of all data along with images.

This sample demonstrates a multi-stage approach to loading and displaying a UITableView. It begins by loading the relevant text from an RSS feed so the table can load as quickly as possible, and then downloads the images for each row asynchronously so the UI is more responsive.

Comment: but thats for web data where as we have local data

Comment: its not necessary that we should lazy load web data only as lazy loading implies numerous data from local also

Answer (score 1):

With ten thousand rows you have no choice but load your data on demand. Otherwise, your app has no chance of performing at a decent level. A freeze like you describe would definitely be enough to see your app rejected<sup>1</sup>.

This approach is rather wasteful with memory, too, because out of ten thousand rows you need at most two dozen at any given time.

A reasonably simple way to speed things up is to prepare an `NSCache` for your pages of data (say, ten items per page), add code that gets the total count of records, and modify the code that retrieves the data to read records from a single page (use [`LIMIT/OFFSET`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt)). When your table shows rows, it should try getting a page of the row from the cache. If the page is not there, it should load it from sqlite, and put in the cache. Using pages will minimize the number of roundtrips to the database; using cache will let you manage an optimal use of memory.

---

<sup>1</sup> It does not look like your app has been rejected for a freeze this time around, but once you fix the "lacking native iOS functionality", the freeze will trigger another rejection.

Comment: but we have search bar, so if we load only some items and user searches for something exists in database, we may not be able to show right?

Comment: @cnu You should be able to use this approach anyway, with or without the search bar. Changing to the search bar should invalidate the cache. You also need to fetch the new count, and tell the table to refresh. Everything else will happen automatically.